# Creating a variable using select portions of an excel column

Tags: r

Let's say I have an excel column with 10 different cells with values. How do I create a variable in r that includes only the first four or first 6 cells in that column?

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: Provided that you save the excel sheet it in a text format such as .csv then it is straightforward to import the data in R using simple base functions such as `read.table` and `scan`.

Answer (score 0):

This question is very vague, please provide more information if you need specifics...

First of all, you'll want to use a library to import the contents of the excel file, I recommend using readxl (http://readxl.tidyverse.org)

You can then follow the documentation to read specific ranges from the excel file or just import all the contents and trim the resulting tibble.

Answer (score 0):

Probably

```
# Install -readxl- package that loads in Excel spreadsheets
install.packages("readxl")
# Load -readxl- package for use
require(readxl)

# Change working directory to directory where spreadsheet is saved in
setwd("<Insert path here>")

# Save spreadsheet data to memory
myData <- read_excel("myData.xlsx", sheet = 1)

# Subset first four or six observations
firstFour <- myData[1:4,]
firstSix <- myData[1:6,]
```

Let me know if you don't understand.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. I ended up using firstFour <-myData$column[1:4]